# If statment for if a variable doesn't exist?

Tags: php

I'm very new to PHP and this is throwing me for a loop.

So I understand some basic PHP IF statements, such as "if contains" "more than" but when it comes to my example; I'm a little confused.

The code below is for the SEO Title Tag. Currently it just echo's the following example:

The Hobbit Poster #1 - Movie Posters

How would I go about creating an IF Statment where if movie_name and poster_name doesn't exist then it just echo's "Movie Posters"

```
<title><?php echo $movie['movie_name']; ?> <?php echo $poster['poster_name']; ?> - Movie Posters</title>
```

Comment: Look at `isset()` and / or `empty()` depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it another way:

> IF (you have a movie_name OR a poster_name) show the DASH

```
<title><?php 
    $separator='';
    if (isset($movie['movie_name'])) { echo $movie['movie_name'].' '; $separator='- '; }
    if (isset($poster['poster_name'])) { echo $poster['poster_name'].' '; $separator='- '; }
    echo $separator;
?>Movie Posters</title>
```

Comment: WHY the downvote? this is one of the most elegant solutions to this type of issue, also bug-free

Answer (score 2):

Option 1:

```
<title><?php echo (isset($movie['movie_name'])) ? $movie['movie_name'] : ''; ?> <?php echo (isset($poster['poster_name'])) ? $poster['poster_name'] : ''; ?> - Movie Posters</title>
```

Option 2:

```
$movie_name = (isset($movie['movie_name'])) ? $movie['movie_name'] : '';
$poster_name = (isset($poster['poster_name'])) ? $poster['poster_name'] : '';

<title><?php echo $movie_name; ?> <?php echo $poster_name; ?> - Movie Posters</title>
```

There are a bunch of ways to do this. Hopefully these point you in the right direction.

Comment: The only problem with those 2 options is that if poster_name and movie_name don't exist it will echo " - Movie Posters"  (It needs to not have the initial space the "-" and then the second space before Movie Posters.

Comment: Yes, but it isn't tough to figure out how to get rid of that. The second option would be the way to get started on that.

Comment: ternary operators are great unless the programmer nests them. Then they are evidence of failure. isset($movie['movie_name']) ? (isset($poster['poster_name']) ? isset($poster['poster_name']) : '') : '' ... I had to deal with relatively large sites nesting sometimes 5 - 6 levels deep. It was like solving a rubiks cube. My point is simply that ternaries should only be used at one level. If others are needed, write them in any of the other ways to do so.... not that anyone suggested nesting. Just saying

Comment: also ternary operators are slower to execute on top of harder to read. no point of using them except for glorified one-liners

Comment: @Austin: you would think that but tests show them slower by some reason. full tag `<?php` recommended!

Comment: @TheOptometrist ternary operators are interpreted the same way if...else blocks are, there should be no difference in performance.

Comment: I don't really understand how I would remove the " - " in option 2. As if I'm not mistaken it still ends up coming round to my problem of no knowing how to implement "IF Statment where if movie_name and poster_name doesn't exist" -- Unless I'm missing something, which I may well be haha.

Comment: It took me a little while to understand this BUT I've figured it out and got the code implemented/working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears we're all posting our own proposed solutions here, here's my explanation. Build up a string of everything you have, and then trim up any excess whitespace. Basically builds on @John Conde's method... he pretty much nailed it first time around. This is just a different way of looking at how PHP can be used.

```
// If either are set, echo a dash
if (isset($movie['movie_name']) || isset($poster['poster_name'])) {
    $title = $movie['movie_name'];
    $title .= ' ';
    $title .= $poster['poster_name'];
    $title .= ' - '
}
$title .= 'Movie Posters'

echo trim($title)
```

Also note that you can use the following syntax for echoing variables:

```
<span>Random number: <?= rand() ?></span>
<small><?= $text_to_go_in_small ?></small>
```

Comment: better move all your $title code inside the if or you'll get notices about undefined variables